# Refactoring of Case Statement and Dynamic Operator

Tags: vb.net, refactoring

I have a case statement which compares data by getting parameter such as "eq,ne,gt,..." and so on. Actually this method will filter data by getting filter parameter and filter value. How can I refactor below code? Thanks.

```
                      For iRow As Integer = 1 To ......
                                       .......
                                      columnData = rowData(HeaderIndex)

                                       Case "eq"
                                            If Not (columnData = filterData) Then
                                                arrayDel(iRow) = True
                                                droppedRows += 1
                                            End If

                                        Case "ne"
                                            If Not (columnData <> filterData) Then
                                                arrayDel(iRow) = True
                                                droppedRows += 1
                                            End If

                                        Case "gt"
                                            If Not (columnData > filterData) Then
                                                arrayDel(iRow) = True
                                                droppedRows += 1
                                            End If

                                        Case "ge"
                                            If Not (columnData >= filterData) Then
                                                arrayDel(iRow) = True
                                                droppedRows += 1
                                            End If
```

Comment: That looks like you could use LINQ to clearly reduce complexity. But therefor we need to see more(rowData,filterData,arrayDel,...).

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to have a function that took your string and the column and filter data and simply returned the relevant boolean value.

```
Case "eq"
    return (columnData = filterData)
Case "ne"
    return (columnData <> filterData)
Case "gt"
    return (columnData > filterData)
Case "ge"
    return (columnData >= filterData)
```

This is a lot easier to look at and leaves out the duplicated lines (to be called now in just one place after calling our new function).